# How to get the balance of a contract using web3.js?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, accounts, addresses, balances

I have deployed a contract as follows and determined its balance to be 5000 wei (`value: 5000`):

```
const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
thisContract.deploy({  
    data: bytecode,
    arguments: [ "0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2", 86400]
}).send({
    from: "0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163",
    gas: 5000000 ,
    gasPrice: '3000000000',
    value: 5000 // here I have determined the balance.
}, function(error, transactionHash) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(transactionHash);
    console.log('function exec');
}).then(function(newContractInstance) {
    console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
});
```

I have deployed this contract on `Tobalaba` blockchain ([its github is here.](https://github.com/energywebfoundation/energyweb-client))

The balance of the address by which I developed this contract is `20000000000000000000 wei` as follows :

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163').then(console.log)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 20000000000000000000
```

However, when I get the balance of the contract, it's `0` as follows:

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0xd227398f81bad20882b46ccdffc71058025df341').then(console.log)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 0
```

And here is the information of deployment of this contract:

https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/address/0xd227398f81bad20882b46ccdffc71058025df341

Acoording to which the contract address is `0xD227398f81bAD20882B46ccdFfC71058025df341`

***Is something wrong?***

***IMPORTANT NOTE: I have developed this contract:*** https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/

Meanwhile, when I get the contract address it returns **null**!

```
> thisContract.options.address
null
```

Whereas, regarding to this information (https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/tx/0xb9834bd2ebbbb930208dbb17462169441c6b63542a01a43e3992ecf803cb0734) it have to be deployed, isn't it ? (Please see the screen shot bellow)

[image]

Comment: What node are you connected to? Are you sure it's up-to-date?

Comment: As to why `thisContract.options.address` is `null`, it's because you never assigned an address. You could use `thisContract.options.address = newContractInstance.options.address` in that callback if you want.

Comment: @smarx Thank you, I am using this node : `enode://63c8ce2905100932230c1760fb29d36d08646979d1fd7abfa8393f5e7feaade3c9a078fd85b194ca040c8a0b2c541537f96deb76a7412c87e36cec16fe543e9f@192.168.136.128:30303`

Comment: So you're using a local Parity node? Check its block number and compare to the one on Etherscan to make sure your node is up-to-date.

Comment: @smarx Thank you, Yes I just got its balance again and fortunately it's now `5000 wei` here: https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/address/0xd227398f81bad20882b46ccdffc71058025df341 It was apparently because of synchronization. Thanks

Comment: @smarx now the next step is to close the channel and make a settlement. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```js
balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contract_address);
```